# Redux Saga handling post action logic

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am using React with hooks & Redux saga in my react application.

I have created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-redux-saga-loading-example-tduv5?file=/src/index.js) to represent the scenario I am interested in.

So I have a page and a redux store, in that page I perform some sort of action that involves the store, while this action is happening, I want to display a loading indication to the user because this action might take some time to finish. so I add another state to the store that turns on when an action is in progress, if that state is on I show a loading indication to the user.

My question what is your method of handling post action logic, for example: lets say that after the action has finished successfully I want to redirect the user to a different page. how would you approach this with redux saga?